# Number of capture groups in a regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find the number of capture groups for a regular expression using this PHP function.

```
/**
 * Finds the number of groups in a regular expression
 * @param $regexPatten string The regular expression
 * @return int Returns the number of groups inside the regular expression
 */
public static function numOfGroups($regexPatten)
{
    $regexPatten = str_replace('\\\\', "", $regexPatten); // remove all escaped backslashes
    $regexPatten = str_replace('\\(', "", $regexPatten); // remove all escaped open parentheses
    $regexPatten = str_replace('(?:', "", $regexPatten); // remove all none capture groups

    return substr_count($regexPatten, "("); // count the remaining opening parentheses
}
```

And here is my test:

```
var_dump(Parser::numOfGroups("(test)")); // 1  --  will match: test
var_dump(Parser::numOfGroups("\((test)\)")); // 1  --  will match: (test)
var_dump(Parser::numOfGroups("\\\\\((test)\\\\(\d+)\)")); // 2  --  plain regex: \\\((test)\\(\d+)\)  --  will match: \(test\343)
var_dump(Parser::numOfGroups("((?:test(?: )?)+)")); // 1  --  will match: test test
```

Is there any use cases I have forgotten?

Comment: Character sets `[...(...]` come to mind.

Comment: @vnp but it can't tell if the if the open parentheses are escaped

Comment: I mean you will count such `(` as a capturing one.

Comment: @vnp Sure, but is should not be counted if there is a \  before the (

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?  You are trying to build a regex parser?

Comment: @MikeBrant I am trying to get the number of capturing groups in a regular expression

Comment: @200_success is this an acceptable way to do it?

Comment: But why?  Are you expecting to get arbitrary regular expression passed to this method that you need to get metadata for?  Do you really need to know this information before the regex is run (at which point you can typically easily count the number of capturing groups if there is a pattern match)?

Comment: No, don't add _any_ new code or fixed code to the question based on an answer.

Comment: You say this is part of a router. So it sounds like you might be trying to extract controllers/methods/parameters from a URI (or other route definition). Can this not be done programmatically after the regex is run? Perhaps it would help to show more context to what you are doing, as this whole approach seems a little strange to me unless you are trying to somehow evaluate the regex itself rather than the outcomes from applying the regex.

Comment: @MikeBrant I am trying to give the option to set a regex for a url parameter in a router, I would have skipped all the capturing groups inside the regex, and then go to the next parameter. But you are right about the testing the parameter after the main regex has been run.

Comment: @MikeBrant But the reason I chose not to do this in the first place was to let the developer use / in the developers own patterns, but it may not be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider non-capturing groups

```
(?:/*pattern*/)
```

These will match your regex but won't normally be operated on in whatever code is running the regex you're evaluating.

Comment: This is not a bad idea, but the function is part of a router, and I can imagine people who use the router are going to forget this :(

Comment: but I have forgotten to remove non-capturing groups, thank you for that insight

Comment: I will force the developers to use none capture groups